# Read a feature class in a variable

Tags: arcpy

Let's assume I have a geodatabase "database.gdb", and inside this database there is a feature class called "feature".

How can I load this feature in memory using arcpy? I have searched into the arcpy 
docs and couldn't find anything useful.

I tried to use Copy_management and CreateFeatureclass_management but its look like these methods expects files instead of variables.

Comment: There are thousands of ArcPy questions asked and answered at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SearchCursor:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm

for example:

```
fc = 'database.gdb/feature'
columns = ['column1', 'column2']

results = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, columns) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        results.append([row[0], row[1]])
```

in this case, the whole "feature" feature class is stored in the list "results"